# get error in run time

Tags: c#, process

I write code for display any process from one list to another list but get error! What am I missing?

```
private void lsvproccess_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lsvitems.Items.Clear();
    ListView lsvview = new ListView();
    int index = lsvview.FocusedItem.Index;  /*( get error in run time )*/

    Process p = new Process();
    p = (Process)process_array[index];

    Detail_process(p);    // detailing each process in right side listview
    try
    {
        // calling Get_modules() method to acquire whole modules 
        // cooperating in this process
        if (chbxmodule.Checked)
            Get_modules(p.Modules);
    }
    catch (Win32Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Presumably a new ListView will not have a FocusedItem as there are no items ...

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you are trying to do, but I am pretty certain it is due to the fact you are trying to set the index of a focused item on a ListView you just instantiated.

Again though, without a better understanding of what it is you are trying to accomplish, I don't think I can give much more in the way of resolving the issue.

Comment: i write this code " in private void lsvproccess_ItemMouseHover(object sender, ListViewItemMouseHoverEventArgs e) " and work really good but i have not  this in c# 2010 or i cannot find it

Answer (score 1):

you have created a new listItem here

```
 ListView lsvview = new ListView();
 int index = lsvview.FocusedItem.Index;
```

and then trying to get the selected item from this empty list which is the reason of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void lsvproccess_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lsvitems.Items.Clear();
    ListView lsvview = new ListView();
    if (lsvview.FocusedItem != null) { // <-- google "C# null reference"
        int index = lsvview.FocusedItem.Index;

        Process p = new Process();
        p = (Process)process_array[index];

        Detail_process(p);    // detailing each process in right side listview
        try
        {
            // calling Get_modules() method to acquire whole modules 
            // cooperating in this process
            if (chbxmodule.Checked)
                Get_modules(p.Modules);
        }
        catch (Win32Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message, this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int index=lsvview.FocusedItem.Index;  /*( get error in run time )*/
```

should be

```
int index=lsvproccess.FocusedItem.Index;
```

This is according to your event: `lsvproccess_SelectedIndexChanged`

This event fires because of you changed the selection of its item, so `lsvproccess` would have a `FocusedItem`, then you should not get NRE.

Unless you specifically changed the name of the event.

Answer (score 0):

you have clear your list  . I think you want to this for see below code

please remove below lines

```
lsvitems.Items.Clear();
    ListView lsvview = new ListView();
```